# How and when to use the generic type parameter in impl block in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I am confused about the generic parameter for the `impl` keyword in Rust.

To explain what I am confused about, I am currently going through the rustling exercises. I am doing the generics part. The second question which can be seen [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/6588d9be22b511c98520de4f4df0c3939aae610e/exercises/generics/generics2.rs#L8) is to make the `Wrapper` struct generic.

Easy, the solution is:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Wrapper { value }
    }
}
```

But I ask myself, why does `impl` have to also have a type parameter? Why `impl<T> Wrapper<T>` and not just `impl Wrapper<T>`?

I could not answer that question but on moving on to the next exercise, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/6588d9be22b511c98520de4f4df0c3939aae610e/exercises/generics/generics3.rs#L1) there is another generic question, which I solved by having this:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub struct ReportCard<T:Display> {
    pub grade: T,
    pub student_name: String,
    pub student_age: u8,
}

impl<T:Display> ReportCard<T> {
    pub fn print(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} ({}) - achieved a grade of {}",
            &self.student_name, &self.student_age, &self.grade.to_string())
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering, why is this right, and the following wrong:

```
pub struct ReportCard<T:Display> {
    pub grade: T,
    pub student_name: String,
    pub student_age: u8,
}

impl<T:Display> ReportCard<T:Display> {
    pub fn print(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} ({}) - achieved a grade of {}",
            &self.student_name, &self.student_age, &self.grade.to_string())
    }
}
```

I think the crux of my problem is, I do not really understand the generics syntax. And where to put the generic type parameter, especially when there is an `impl` block.

Does anyone have an explanation on how these syntax is supposed to be used?

Comment: Don't forget that you can write `impl ReportCard<u32> { fn some_function_here() { ... } }`. Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could think of it the same way a function takes parameters, and can feed back these parameters in a function call, and it will probably make sense.

A generic type `Wrapper<T>` is "like" a function that takes a type `T`, and produces an actual, concrete type `Wrapper<T>` (even though there is no difference in the syntax, just like there is no difference when you define a function and when you call it to get an actual value out of it).

Similarly, an `impl` block is "like" a function that may take some parameters, and that produces a given implementation for a given type. That is, `impl<T> Wrapper<T> { ... }` should be read like *define a generic implementation that takes a parameter, `T`, and that produces an  actual, concrete implementation `{ ... }` for the concrete type `Wrapper<T>`*, which, in this case, can be seen as the "function call" rather than the "signature declaration".

But, for instance, you could also choose not to make your implementation generic: `impl Wrapper<u32> { ... }`, or even to make it generic over several arguments, not use none in the `Wrapper<T>` "call": `impl<T, U> Wrapper<char> { ... }` because these type parameters can also be used in the actual implementation.

---

This being said, we can now look at the syntax more in details. Usually, when you define a "generic block" (that is, a generic `impl`, or a generic `struct`, or a generic `enum`, or ...), the first keyword of that block may also specify some times with the `<T, U, ...>` syntax, which you may think as in a function definition. Every subsequent usage of these types in the block through the same syntax may be though of as a "function call": you feed these arguments into an other "function".

For this reason, you can only add constraints over these types in the first `<...>` part of an `impl` block, not after the type:

```rust
impl<T: Display> Wrapper<T> { ... }
```

is valid, because it means *given a type `T` such that `T` implements the trait `Display`, I can provide an implementation for the concrete type `Wrapper<T>`*, but

```rust
impl<T: Display> Wrapper<T: Display> { ... }
```

is not valid, and neither is

```rust
impl<T> Wrapper<T: Display> { ... }
```

because you are putting constrains on a "function call". Just like

```rust
fn something(a: usize) {
  something_else(a);
}
```

is valid, but not

```rust
fn something(a: usize) {
  something_else(a: usize)
}
```

nor

```rust
fn something(a) {
  something_else(a: usize)
}
```